# Getting the maximum range of a mic

Tags: sound

I've asked yesterday a question about choosing a mic, and I conclude that I need a mic  that can "hear" a sound louder than 160SPL , after Googling and reading wikis about mics, I still can't find a mic or a technology, that could serve my purpose. so my question  is which mic is appropriate for this kind of projects:

- Dynamic microphone
- Condenser microphone
- Piezoelectric microphone
- etc.

I'm asking this because in the datasheet of the mic there nothing mentioning that expects for the MEMS mics but the specified range was 135SPL which is not enough for the project.

Comment: For very high SPL, couldn't you just put an attenuator around the microphone? Or do you need accurate reproduction across a very high dynamic range?

Comment: No I really need the original sound without any kind of changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had another look.  Dynamic microphones don't generally have a maximum SPL - see this site: http://recordinghacks.com/2008/02/26/maximum-spl-of-dynamic-microphones/

The gist of it is that anything loud enough to cause a dynamic mic to distort is likely to permanently distort your ears.

Dynamic mics don't have a really flat frequency response, though, so if that is important you might have to do some compensation in your application.

Dynamic mics also have a lower signal level, so you might need an amplifier with more gain and lower noise.

I've found info on piezo mics that claim SPL from 100 upto 180 dB, specifically for picking up engine noises - look for Endevco as one of the manufacturers.  Seems they won't be much good for low level sound, and they are only (relatively) flat up to around 10kHz.  Might be worth a look.

Comment: 1. thanks for you help, 2. can you say the same thing about Piezo Mic,  I know that Condenser Mics cause clipping in the signal

Comment: I don't know if piezos have the same limitation. The hint about the maximum SPL for the dynmics came from folks who regularly record loud sounds - sound engineers recording kick drum with the mic in the drum, which causes some VERY loud sounds.  They don't use piezos, though.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure sensors are the likely answer: -

- 165 dB SPL is 4000 pascals\$_{(RMS)}\$ (newtons force per sq metre)
- 4000 pascals are 0.58015 pounds per sq inch (PSI) or a peak pressure that is \$\sqrt2\$ higher

There are plenty of pressure sensors around that can do this and have a pretty flat frequency response in the audio region. [Here](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=2031+215301+110539929+110205831+110123539+110201779&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=pressure+sensor&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=2031+215301&mm=1002180||,1002421||,1001880||,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=%2Fjsp%2Fsearch%2Fbrowse.jsp%3FN%3D2031%2B215301%26Ntk%3Dgensearch%26Ntt%3Dpressure%2Bsensor%26Ntx%3Dmode%2Bmatchallpartial%26No%3D0%26getResults%3Dtrue%26appliedparametrics%3Dtrue%26locale%3Den_UK%26divisionLocale%3Den_UK%26catalogId%3D%26skipManufacturer%3Dfalse%26skipParametricAttributeId%3D%26prevNValues%3D2031%2B215301) is a search result in Farnell for pressure sensors having a peak PSI of 1 pound per sq inch.